# How do I represent "Any string except for .... "

Tags: regex, regular-language, computation-theory

I'm trying to solve a regex where the given alphabet is Σ={a,b}

The first expression is:

```
L1 = {a^2n b^(3m+1) | n >= 1, m >= 0}
```

which means the corresponding regex is: `aa(a)*b(bbb)*`

What would be a regex for L2, complement of L1?
Is it right to assume L2 = "Any string except for aa(a)*b(bbb)*"?

Comment: I have to represent L2 = L1 
L stand for the complement of L;
Assume that alphabet Σ={a,b}

Answer (score 3):

First, in my opinion, the regex for `L1 = {a^2n b^3m+1 | n>=1, m>=0}`
is NOT what you gave but is: `aa(aa)*b(bbb)*`. The reason is that `a^2n, n > 1` means that there are at least 2 `a` and a pair number of `a`.

Now, the regular expression for `"Any string except for aa(aa)*b(bbb)*"` is:

```
^(?!^aa(aa)*b(bbb)*$).*$
```

more details here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yI3vR2/2)

Explanations

- `aa(a)*b(bbb)*` the regex you DON'T want to match
- `^` represents begining of line
- `(?!)` negative lookahead: should NOT match what's in this group
- `$` represents end of line

---

**EDIT**

Yes, a complement for `aa(aa)*b(bbb)*` is `"Any string but the ones that match aa(aa)*b(bbb)*"`.

Now you need to find a regex that represents that with the syntax that you can use. I gave you a regex in this answer that is correct and matches `"Any string but the ones that match aa(aa)*b(bbb)*"`, but if you want a  mathematical representation following the pattern you gave for L1, you'll need to find something simpler.

Without any negative lookahead, that would be:

```
L2 = ^((b+.*)|((a(aa)*)?b*)|a*((bbb)*|bb(bbb)*)|(.*a+))$
```

Test it here at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eS7zB5/1)

Good luck with the mathematical representation translation...

Comment: Is it right to represent ^((?!aa(a)*b(bbb)*))*$ in computation theory way?

Comment: @Tim007 a negative lookahead, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Comment: @Azr4el What? You wanted a regex that matches any string that didn't match the given regex, here's one. I don't know about computation theory way...

Comment: @Azr4el Maybe that's not what you wanted, if so please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @adrien-brunelat i don't ask about negative lookahead or regex stuff and things : D, just because your answer doesn't make sense to Azr4el's question.

Comment: You question didn't make sense. But with the new edit, I get what you want and I'm working on it.

Comment: @Azr4el Hmm... You just validated my answer, but it doesn't match with your last edit. What is happening?

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat it was a misclick Im sorry.

Comment: @Azr4el are you allowed to use some kind of `OR` syntax in the L2 mathematical expression?

Comment: @Azr4el And what about a `NOT`?

Comment: @adrien-brunelat your regex will fail in `aabb` that should matches by L2 but not L1

Answer (score 0):

The first expression is:

```
L1 = {a^2n b^(3m+1) | n >= 1, m >= 0}
```

Regex for L1 is:

```
^aa(?:aa)*b(?:bbb)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ2mP0/1)
Input

```
a
b
ab
aab
abb
aaab
aabb
abbb
aaaab
aaabb
aabbb
abbbb
aaaaab
aaaabb
aaabbb
aabbbb
abbbbb
aaaaaab
aaaaabb
aaaabbb
aaabbbb
aabbbbb
abbbbbb
aaaabbbb
```

Matches

```
MATCH 1
1.  [7-10]  `aab`
MATCH 2
1.  [30-35] `aaaab`
MATCH 3
1.  [75-81] `aabbbb`
MATCH 4
1.  [89-96] `aaaaaab`
MATCH 5
1.  [137-145]   `aaaabbbb`
```

Regex for L2, complement of L1

```
^aa(?:aa)*b(?:bbb)*$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^.*$
```

**Explanation**:
`^aa(?:aa)*b(?:bbb)*$` matches L1
`^aa(?:aa)*b(?:bbb)*$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` anything matches L1 will skip & fail
`|^.*$` matches others that not matches L1
[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sY2xJ1/1)
Matches

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-1]   `a`
MATCH 2
1.  [2-3]   `b`
MATCH 3
1.  [4-6]   `ab`
MATCH 4
1.  [11-14] `abb`
MATCH 5
1.  [15-19] `aaab`
MATCH 6
1.  [20-24] `aabb`
MATCH 7
1.  [25-29] `abbb`
MATCH 8
1.  [36-41] `aaabb`
MATCH 9
1.  [42-47] `aabbb`
MATCH 10
1.  [48-53] `abbbb`
MATCH 11
1.  [54-60] `aaaaab`
MATCH 12
1.  [61-67] `aaaabb`
MATCH 13
1.  [68-74] `aaabbb`
MATCH 14
1.  [82-88] `abbbbb`
MATCH 15
1.  [97-104]    `aaaaabb`
MATCH 16
1.  [105-112]   `aaaabbb`
MATCH 17
1.  [113-120]   `aaabbbb`
MATCH 18
1.  [121-128]   `aabbbbb`
MATCH 19
1.  [129-136]   `abbbbbb`
```